# dependent N level dropdown list

Tags: php, dropdown

newbie in PHP, did search a lot and could not find what the related links to help me to write the code. Saw lots of post about a dependent drop-down menu, like country/state/city, or display multiple drop-down values...

what my idea is similar to a shopping cart system, but it is not a shopping cart, just customer fill in the form to let the website owner know what product he is interested in getting more information.

When choosing the 1st main drop-down menu, like CATEGORIES, 
it will popup related SUB-CATEGORIES, and till sub-categories, not having any more sub-categories, and the related last sub-categories will show up the related PRODUCT(S). So it is not pre-defined option/selection, as the website owner may be just start with 3 levels of sub-categories, and/or later add up to 7 or more levels sub-categories if needed.

Did google search and found script that can allow multiple selection with drop-down list, however it is only good to select from same one drop-down menu, not practical if user want to have new categories and/or new sub-categories, so need to have options from drop-down list for user to select OPTION1: finish adding products or OPTION2: continue add more new categories/products.

all the value from the drop-down list needs to be able to display and retrieve from the database via a form action. There are few version of script been mentioned, what is the best one to achieve my ideas? Jason?

---

### database tables include:

customers / categories / products / products to categories

---

### form:

for a customer to enter basic customer details, 
select and submit interested categories & product(s)

---

### actions (3):

submit the form to save it to the database, 
display customer's selected product on screen, and 
send form result via email to web owner and customers.
Many thanks!

Comment: You can AJAX to dynamically fetch the corresponding dropdowns, Say for example, you have the COUNTRY dropdown, and you can attach an event handler for `change` event of that dropdown, which will fetch the list of STATES via AJAX. And you can add another event handle for the `change` event of this STATES dropdown, which would fetch the CITIES when user selects an item. Did that help?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is nothing for Stackoverflow in my opinion. I tried to make an example for you but this takes very long (more than one hour now). My general idea so far is:

Create a `model` class which handles your database connection. Save the already answered categories. Then ask the `model` if there are more categories to select. As an example you have the categories

```
$categories = array(
    'Intel' => array(
        'i7',
        'i9'
    ),
    'AMD' => array(
        'Ryzen',
        'Athlon'
    )
);
```

The user starts with the first question which is fixed.

```
<legend for='0'>Which brand do you want?</legend>
<select id='0'>
    <option value='1'>Intel</option>
    <option value='2'>AMD</option>
</select>
```

Your database then contains the table `categories [id, name, parent]`. The first category is a dummy. The table may look like this:

```
+---+--------+------+
| 0 | NULL   | NULL |
| 1 | Intel  | 0    |
| 2 | AMD    | 0    |
| 3 | i7     | 1    |
| 4 | i9     | 1    |
| 5 | Ryzen  | 2    |
| 6 | Athlon | 2    |
+---+--------+------+
```

As a default you use the `id = 0` as "selected". The subcategories, so the categories with the current category (`0`) as their parents, will then be displayed.

Whenever the user selects one selectbox, you have the selected ID. By using this id you can iterate over your table (by using a `php` loop which is inefficient) and store all the parent ids (so the parent, the grandparent, the grandgrandparent, ...) until the parent is `0`. The parent ids together with your selected answer will give you the "path" to this current category. You know all the previously selected categories.

Your product table then may look like `product[id, category_id, name, ...]`.

Whenever the user changes the category, you will have to select and display all the categories, that have the user selected one as their parent. In addition you will have to display all the products with the given `category_id` (the user selected first one).

You can then save the product ids to a `basket` table. This table contains all procuts the customer bought.

I would do it by using a template in html. This will show the previously selected categories. The categories can then be parsed by using this template to show it to the user. In addition I would use ajax requests to speed the page up and to prevent loading everything again and again.